# Python 3 - Accessing multiple dictionaries in a single .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a single file called foods.py which contains 3 dictionaries (foodA, foodB, and foodC).  If I were to import foods into a different .py file, how can I print out (or access) the dictionary names (foodA, foodB, and foodC) when using a script that has 'import foods'?  I am using Python 3.

```
-------------------foods.py-------------------
foodA = {'Protein': '10','Carbs': '80','Fat': '10'}
foodB = {'Protein': '20', 'Carbs': '0', 'Fat': '102'}
foodC = {'Protein': '90', 'Carbs': '10', 'Fat': '100'}
```

I've tried the following:

```
import foods

for x in foods:
    print(foods.x)
```

But, this doesn't work because foods is not iterable. I am looking for the following output:

```
foodA
foodB
foodC
```

For the second part, how can I access each element of each dictionary?  I have included the following as an example.

```
import foods

print(foods.foodA['Protein'])
print(foods.foodA['Carbs'])
print(foods.foodB['Protein'])
print(foods.foodB['Carbs'])
print(foods.foodC['Protein'])
print(foods.foodC['Carbs'])
```

This works for accessing values of the keys, but I am looking for an 'iterable' approach so I don't need to type out each individual statement.  This example has only 3 dictionaries in one file, but my program has over 200 dictionaries in a single .py file.

So, I am looking at the most efficient way for (1) printing out the name of each dictionary within the single .py file and (2) accessing key/value pairs for each dictionary within the single .py file.

Comment: Why not just define a dictionary `{"A": {...}, ...}` in `foods`? Then it's iterable (and is probably the thing you want to be doing).

Answer (score 3):

as Larry Lustig mentioned. Just create nested dictionaries called foods

```
foods={'foodA':{'Protein':'10','Carbs':'80','Fat':'10'},'foodB':{'Protein':'20','Carbs':'0','Fat':'102'},'foodC':{'Protein':'90','Carbs':'10','Fat':'100'}}
```

Then you can access the values of all the elements using something like

```
for key,val in foods.items():
    print(key)
    for _key,_val in val.items():
        print("\t"+str(_key)+" "+str(_val))
```

And that gives you:

```
foodB
    Carbs 0
    Fat 102
    Protein 20
foodC
    Carbs 10
    Fat 100
    Protein 90
foodA
    Carbs 80
    Fat 10
    Protein 10
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can read out a list of all symbol names exported by a module using `dir()`, and then you can look up their values through the module's `__dict__` attribute.

```
import foods
foods_names = [name for name in dir(foods) if name.startswith('food')]
foods_values = dict((name, foods.__dict__[name]) for name in foods_names)
print(foods_values)
```

Result:

```
{'foodB': {'Fat': '102', 'Protein': '20', 'Carbs': '0'},
 'foodA': {'Fat': '10', 'Protein': '10', 'Carbs': '80'},
 'foodC': {'Fat': '100', 'Protein': '90', 'Carbs': '10'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

**foods.py:**

```
foods = {
    'foodA': {'Protein': '10','Carbs': '80','Fat': '10'},
    'foodB': {'Protein': '20','Carbs': '0','Fat': '102'},
    'foodC': {'Protein': '90','Carbs': '10','Fat': '100'}
}
```

**Your code (main file):**

```
from foods import foods

for food in foods:
    foodKey = (food)
    for attribute in foods[foodKey].items():
        print attribute[0], attribute[1]
```

**Results:**

```
Protein 10
Carbs 80
Fat 10
Protein 90
Carbs 10
Fat 100
Protein 20
Carbs 0
Fat 102
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your commands like `for x in foods:` don't work because you have no variable or entity named `foods`, and nothing that behaves like a collection of foods either.  You only have three, separate, food items and you would have to address them by name, for example `for x in (foodA, foodB, foodC):`.

That would get kind of tedious as the number of foods grows.  Therefore, you should rewrite foods.py like this:

```
foods = {
   'foodA' : {'Protein': '10','Carbs': '80','Fat': '10'}
   'foodB' : {'Protein': '20', 'Carbs': '0', 'Fat': '102'}
   'foodC' : {'Protein': '90', 'Carbs': '10', 'Fat': '100'}
}
```

and now you can write

```
from foods import foods

for x in foods.keys():
   print(x)

print foods['foodA']['Protein']
```

Comment: Hello, I am using the following line within a for loop to create that single .py file:

resultFile.write(str(food) + ' = ' + pprint.pformat(Data))

The result is multiple dictionaries printed into a single .py file.  In your example, the entire file is only one dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the two files are in the same directory, then use the following format:

```
    from foods import foodA
    from foods import foodB
    from foods import foodC

    print(foodA)
    print(foodB)
    print(foodC)

    print(foodA["Carbs"])
```

The headers will call the code into the new file. I printed the dictionaries, just to show you that it worked. Next, I called the a key from FoodA so that it yields the proper result. You can call as many dictionaries as you need using this method. Unfortunately,. Stack Overflow is not letting me paste my output into the reply. I am not sure why. This should work though. Let me know if you still have difficulties.